# dplyr - filter by group size

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr, subset

What is the best way to filter a data.frame to only get groups of say size 5?

So my data looks as follows:

```
require(dplyr)
n <- 1e5
x <- rnorm(n)
# Category size ranging each from 1 to 5
cat <- rep(seq_len(n/3), sample(1:5, n/3, replace = TRUE))[1:n]

dat <- data.frame(x = x, cat = cat)
```

The dplyr way i could come up with was

```
dat <- group_by(dat, cat)

system.time({
  out1 <- dat %>% filter(n() == 5L)
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.157   0.218   1.497
```

But this is very slow... Is there a better way in dplyr?

So far my workaround solutions looks as follows:

```
system.time({
  all_ind <- rep(seq_len(n_groups(dat)), group_size(dat))
  take_only <- which(group_size(dat) == 5L)
  out2 <- dat[all_ind %in% take_only, ]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.026   0.008   0.036
all.equal(out1, out2) # TRUE
```

But this doesn't feel very dplyr like...

Comment: Wait until you see the data.table solution. Not dplyery at all.

Comment: Easy too. Something like `setDT(dat)[, if(.N == 5) .SD, by = cat]`

Comment: A faster approach in data.table would be `setDT(dat)[dat[, .I[.N==5], by = cat]$V1]`

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli: Guessing you mean `m`: Yes it is ordered.

Comment: @akrun: It seams Sotos answer is faster. See below

Comment: @Floo0  Okay, anyway you asked for a dplyr solution

Comment: `dat[dat$cat %in% rle(dat$cat)$values[rle(dat$cat)$lengths==5], ]`. I think this is faster.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli: Great answer. Just added it below

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do it more concisely with `n()`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(cat) %>% filter(n() == 5)
```

Comment: If you've read the "The dplyr way i could come up with was" part of the question, you would've known that he/she already tried this. It was considered too slow by the OP.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another dplyr approach you can try

```
semi_join(dat, count(dat, cat) %>% filter(n == 5), by = "cat")
```

--

Here's another approach based on OP's original approach with a little modification:

```
n <- 1e5
x <- rnorm(n)
# Category size ranging each from 1 to 5
cat <- rep(seq_len(n/3), sample(1:5, n/3, replace = TRUE))[1:n]

dat <- data.frame(x = x, cat = cat)

# second data set for the dt approch
dat2 <- data.frame(x = x, cat = cat)

sol_floo0 <- function(dat){
  dat <- group_by(dat, cat)
  all_ind <- rep(seq_len(n_groups(dat)), group_size(dat))
  take_only <- which(group_size(dat) == 5L)
  dat[all_ind %in% take_only, ]
}

sol_floo0_v2 <- function(dat){
  g <- group_by(dat, cat) %>% group_size()
  ind <- rep(g == 5, g)
  dat[ind, ]
}



microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times = 10,
                               sol_floo0(dat),
                               sol_floo0_v2(dat2))
#Unit: milliseconds
#               expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#     sol_floo0(dat) 43.72903 44.89957 45.71121 45.10773 46.59019 48.64595    10   b
# sol_floo0_v2(dat2) 29.83724 30.56719 32.92777 31.97169 34.10451 38.31037    10  a 
all.equal(sol_floo0(dat), sol_floo0_v2(dat2))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats a huge speedup compared to my `filter` solution. Still looking for a solution that beats my second _hybrid_ solution...

Comment: The second version is nearly as fast as DT solution with the grouping included. Great one

Answer (score 6):

I know you asked for a `dplyr` solution but if you combine it with some `purrr` you can get it in one line without specifying any new functions. (A little slower though.)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(cat) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(n = map(data, n_distinct)) %>%
  unnest(n = n) %>% 
  filter(n == 5) %>% 
  select(cat, n)
```

Answer (score 2):

Comparing the answers timewise:

```
require(dplyr)
require(data.table)
n <- 1e5
x <- rnorm(n)
# Category size ranging each from 1 to 5
cat <- rep(seq_len(n/3), sample(1:5, n/3, replace = TRUE))[1:n]

dat <- data.frame(x = x, cat = cat)

# second data set for the dt approch
dat2 <- data.frame(x = x, cat = cat)

sol_floo0 <- function(dat){
  dat <- group_by(dat, cat)
  all_ind <- rep(seq_len(n_groups(dat)), group_size(dat))
  take_only <- which(group_size(dat) == 5L)
  dat[all_ind %in% take_only, ]
}

sol_floo0_v2 <- function(dat){
  g <- group_by(dat, cat) %>% group_size()
  ind <- rep(g == 5, g)
  dat[ind, ]
}

sol_docendo_discimus <- function(dat){ 
  dat <- group_by(dat, cat)
  semi_join(dat, count(dat, cat) %>% filter(n == 5), by = "cat")
}

sol_akrun <- function(dat2){
  setDT(dat2)[dat2[, .I[.N==5], by = cat]$V1]
}

sol_sotos <- function(dat2){
  setDT(dat2)[, if(.N == 5) .SD, by = cat]
}

sol_chirayu_chamoli <- function(dat){
  rle_ <- rle(dat$cat)
  dat[dat$cat %in% rle_$values[rle_$lengths==5], ]
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times = 20,
                               sol_floo0(dat),
                               sol_floo0_v2(dat),
                               sol_docendo_discimus(dat), 
                               sol_akrun(dat2),
                               sol_sotos(dat2),
                               sol_chirayu_chamoli(dat))
```

Results in:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval  cld
            sol_floo0(dat)  58.00439  65.28063  93.54014  69.82658  82.79997 280.23114    20   cd
         sol_floo0_v2(dat)  42.27791  50.27953  72.51729  58.63931  67.62540 238.97413    20  bc 
 sol_docendo_discimus(dat) 100.54095 113.15476 126.74142 121.69013 132.62533 183.05818    20    d
           sol_akrun(dat2)  26.88369  34.01925  41.04378  37.07957  45.44784  63.95430    20 ab  
           sol_sotos(dat2)  16.10177  19.78403  24.04375  23.06900  28.05470  35.83611    20 a   
  sol_chirayu_chamoli(dat)  20.67951  24.18100  38.01172  27.61618  31.97834 230.51026    20 ab
```

Comment: Just for good measure, you should include the `group_by` step in the timing of your function too

Comment: @docendodiscimus: You are right for a SO question it is better. In my analysis i already have them grouped. Thats why i excluded it in the measurements...

Comment: `sol_docendo_discimus` does not require the `group_by` call! That's why the runtime is so high.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way of accelerating the dplyr-way `n()` filter is to store the result in a new column. The initial time of calculating the group size is amortised if there are multiple `filter`s later on.

```r
library(dplyr)

prep_group <- function(dat) {
    dat %>%
        group_by(cat) %>%
        mutate(
            Occurrences = n()
        ) %>%
        ungroup()
}

# Create a new data frame with the `Occurrences` column:
# dat_prepped <- dat %>% prep_group
```

Filtering the `Occurrences` field is much faster than the workaround solution:

```r
sol_floo0 <- function(dat){
    dat <- group_by(dat, cat)
    all_ind <- rep(seq_len(n_groups(dat)), group_size(dat))
    take_only <- which(group_size(dat) == 5L)
    dat[all_ind %in% take_only, ]
}

sol_floo0_v2 <- function(dat){
    g <- group_by(dat, cat) %>% group_size()
    ind <- rep(g == 5, g)
    dat[ind, ]
}

sol_cached <- function(dat) {
    out <- filter(dat, Occurrences == 5L)
}

n <- 1e5
x <- rnorm(n)
# Category size ranging each from 1 to 5
cat <- rep(seq_len(n/3), sample(1:5, n/3, replace = TRUE))[1:n]

dat <- data.frame(x = x, cat = cat)

dat_prepped <- prep_group(dat)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=50, sol_floo0(dat), sol_floo0_v2(dat), sol_cached(dat_prepped))
```

```
Unit: microseconds
                    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval cld
          sol_floo0(dat) 33345.764 35603.446 42430.441 37994.477 41379.411 144103.471    50   c
       sol_floo0_v2(dat) 26180.539 27842.927 29694.203 29089.672 30997.411  37412.899    50  b 
 sol_cached(dat_prepped)   801.402   930.025  1342.348  1098.843  1328.192   5049.895    50 a
```

---

The preparation can be further accelerated by using `count()` -> `left_join()`:

```r
prep_join <- function(dat) {
    dat %>%
        left_join(
            dat %>%
                count(cat, name="Occurrences")
        )
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=10, prep_group(dat), prep_join(dat))
```

```
Unit: milliseconds
            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 prep_group(dat) 45.67805 47.68100 48.98929 49.11258 50.08214 52.44737    10   b
  prep_join(dat) 35.01945 36.20857 37.96460 36.86776 38.71056 45.59041    10  a
```

Answer (score 1):

I generalised the function written by [docendo discimus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43110620/4575331), to use it alongside existing dplyr functions:

```
#' inherit dplyr::filter
#' @param min minimal group size, use \code{min = NULL} to filter on maximal group size only
#' @param max maximal group size, use \code{max = NULL} to filter on minimal group size only
#' @export
#' @source Stack Overflow answer by docendo discimus, \url{https://stackoverflow.com/a/43110620/4575331}
filter_group_size <- function(.data, min = NULL, max = min) {
  g <- dplyr::group_size(.data)
  if (is.null(min) & is.null(max)) {
    stop('`min` and `max` cannot both be NULL.')
  }
  if (is.null(max)) {
    max <- base::max(g, na.rm = TRUE)
  }
  ind <- base::rep(g >= min & g <= max, g)
  .data[ind, ]
}
```

Let's check it for a minimal group size of `5`:

```
dat2 %>%
  group_by(cat) %>%
  filter_group_size(5, NULL) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(n))

# # A tibble: 6,634 x 2
#      cat     n
#    <int> <int>
#  1    NA    19
#  2     1     5
#  3     2     5
#  4     6     5
#  5    15     5
#  6    17     5
#  7    21     5
#  8    27     5
#  9    33     5
# 10    37     5
# # ... with 6,624 more rows
```

Great, now check for the OP's question; a group size of exactly `5`:

```
dat2 %>%
  group_by(cat) %>%
  filter_group_size(5) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  pull(n) %>%
  unique()
# [1] 5
```

Hooray.

Comment: I had some data where this version fails. Seems group_by sorts data and this might result in wrong indices. `data.frame(x=c(2,2,1)) %>% group_by(x) %>% group_size` results in `c(1,2)` instead of `c(2, 1) `

Comment: First, the `group_size()` you use is a function from the `dplyr` package and has nothing to do with my answer. Second, the `group_by()` function from the `dplyr` package sorts groups alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

```
dat %>%
  dplyr::group_by(cat) %>%
  dplyr::add_tally() %>%
  dplyr::filter(n == 5)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer]. This is particularly important when answering old questions (this one is over 4 years old) with existing answers. How does this answer improve upon what's already here (Joe's answer in particular)?